# make Observable optional in zip operator with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have a Observable call with retrofit that zipped three API calls 
but I want to have the 3 calls together , but sometime one of the calls fails but I only have one main call which is mandatory for me and the rest of calls is optional , because when one of them fails it do on Error , and I don't want that, I was thinking if there is like JoinObservable.when(OperatorJoinPatterns.or(call1 , call2 ) .then 
but the only thing is and

```
    Observable.zip(getSearchObservable(FIRST_PAGE), App.getApi().allbookmarks(), SpotlightUtil.getSpotLightBanner(), App.getApi().getFollowingSuggestions(AppConfigUtil.getFollowingSuggestions().getLimit()),
                (searchResult, myFavouritesResults, spotlightListResult, followingSuggestionsResult) -> combineCall(searchResult, myFavouritesResults, spotlightListResult, followingSuggestionsResult, false))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult -> {
//my main call that i want if that fail the request should fail 
                    if (!NetUtils.isServerOk(spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult.getSearchResult().getStatus())) {
                        throw new ServerErrorException(spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult.getSearchResult().getErrorMessage());
                    }

                    if (spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult.getSearchResult().posts.size() < PAGE_SIZE) {
                        rvPosts.setFinished(true);
                    }
                    hideLoader();
                    mPostAdapter.mSuggestions = spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult.getFollowingSuggestionsResult().getSuggestion();
                    checkToAddOrRemoveFeedbackSpotLight(spotlightsAndSearchResultAndSuggestionsResult.getSearchResult().posts, true);
                                    })
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    ErrorScreenUtils.checkError(throwable, this, true);
                    hideLoader();
                })
                .retryWhen(RxActivity.RETRY_CONDITION).compose(bindUntilEvent(FragmentEvent.DESTROY))
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOnError` does not stop error propagation, so it breaks your logic.

For optional source use one of `onErrorResumeNext`, `onErrorReturnItem`, `onErrorReturn` operators. You can replace error with dummy value that can be successfully `zip`ped:

```
Observable.zip(
    source1,
    source2,
    optionalSource3.onErrorReturnItem(stub)
)
...
```